# Superscript inside a p:after content tag

Tags: css, pseudo-element, css-content

```
.class {
    &:after {
        content: "m3/s";
    }
}
```

I want to add a unit declaration via :after tag. Is it possible to make the `3` superscript?

This obviously doesn't work:

```
.class {
    &:after {
        content: "m<sup>3</sup>/s";
    }
}
```

Comment: For 3 in particular, there's a unicode character "superscript 3" ³ you can use.

Comment: The code is not CSS. You are apparently using some language to be translated into CSS. Please specify it or, better, formulate your problem in terms of CSS.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It is `.less` code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't style generated content partially (with the exception of combining `:first-letter` and `:before`), so no. You *could* use U+00B3 SUPERSCRIPT THREE instead:

```
.class {
    &:after {
        content: "m\00B3/s"; /* Or content: "m³/s"; */
    }
}
```

... but I would recommend putting this as actual content and either using U+00B3, `&sup3;` or the `<sup>` element if it is semantically important.

Answer (score 5):

To make any content superscript :

```
.class::after {
    content: "some content";
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    top: -0.5em;
}
```